# Configuring MySQL5 with Hibernate 4, Spring 3, JPA 2 to have 1 exception in the end

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, jpa, mysql5

I know it looks like this subject already exists and I actually found some topic but the answer doesn't work for me. also most of them use use the original hibernate.cfg.xml and I would like to do it using JPA2 and the persistence.xml

So I start a Project using Roo thinking that it would help a lot. and at the beginning it was close to be true. But then come few problem with dependencies and I start getting an exception when starting the server (I use Tomcat7 and/or JBoss EAP6)

it looks like it can't create the persistenceUnit because a method is missing...

```
2013-09-04 16:59:40,191 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ... lots of blabla..



Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 22 more
```

I guess this is due to bad dependencies between hibernate-jpa and ejb3-persistence but I can't make it work. I tried exclusions.. (to finally get that the annotations was not found... has to be something different.

here is my pom.xml (

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <roo.version>1.2.4.RELEASE</roo.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.25</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ROO dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${roo.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <!-- NB: do not use 1.3 or 1.3.x due to MASPECTJ-90 issue  -->
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <!--
                      Aspects in src/main/java and src/main/aspects are added 
                      as default in the compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/test/java and src/test/aspects are added 
                      as default in the test-compile goal.
                      Aspects in src/main/java are added in the test-compile 
                      goal if weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder is set to true
                    -->
                    <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml located in /META-INF/spring/

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

And now the famous persistence.xml located in /META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I finally tried things and it's possible that it still remain in the code (like the JTA transaction type)

Version of jars are in the pom.

Any idea why this is happenning ?!

Comment: If you found similar questions that don't quite answer your specific problem, it wouldn't hurt to mention why that doesn't help (just in case people trying to answer run across them)

Comment: The answer was about putting exclusion on a class in the ejb3-hibernate.jar.
I finally get a problem with annotations not found..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all Hibernate dependencies except `hibernate-entitymanager` (and `hibernate-validator`) - it should be enough.

Comment: Perfect!! actually with the dependencies the hibernate core and all needed jar are downloaded, and in the meantime we avoid what is not useful.
Many Thanks